# fail2ban regex negative-lookahead

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds, fail2ban

I have an `apache access log filter` in `fail2ban` which uses a blacklist of words e.g. `(db|project|wp-admin|wp-content)` which works but due to certain paths and certain gotchas decided to add an `ignoreregex` with negative-lookahead to exclude some of these depending on the path but this does not work as an `ignoreregex` yet is valid.

Sample access log

```
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2016:13:00:42 +0100] "GET /images/imagecache/cache_232dbf2e1e./wp-content/ HTTP/1.1" 404 16 "http://[referrer]" "[user-agent]"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2016:13:10:21 +0100] "GET /images/imagecache/cache_3d87dbea9f./wp-content/ HTTP/1.1" 404 16 "http://[referrer]" "[user-agent]"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2016:13:14:41 +0100] "GET /images/imagecache/cache_232dbf2e1e./wp-content/ HTTP/1.1" 404 16 "http://[referrer]" "[user-agent]"
127.0.0.1 - - [10/Oct/2016:13:21:04 +0100] "GET /images/imagecache/cache_232dbf2e1e. HTTP/1.1" 404 16 "http://[referrer]" "[user-agent]"
```

ignoreregex entry in `filter.d` file

```
.*images\/imagecache.+(db|project).+(?!(wp|wp-admin|wp-content|xampp|xplorer)).+$
```

Using this on something like https://regex101.com correctly matches only the last entry in the log above but using this in my `filter.d` file ignores all 4 entries.  Without the `ignoreregex` all 4 are `matched` with the `ignoreregex` all 4 are `ignored`.

The regex above should match entries with `images/imagecache` and allow a whitelist of words if present in this case `(db|project)` but **not** if any of the blacklist words are present `(?!(wp|wp-admin|wp-content|xampp|xplorer))`.

Comment: Does `fail2ban`'s regex engine actually support lookarounds?

Comment: Apparently yes according to this commit making use of it https://github.com/fail2ban/fail2ban/pull/387/commits/6b519d54dbae9cef64c0174b82df3ded8250f146